# Conditional Cell referencing value along a row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to make a cell display a date conditional on the value of another cell in that dates column.

[This best illustrates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DruTc.png).

On row 8 I have a set of values associated with dates on row 6.  I would like to have a cell that displays the date at which row 8 goes beneath a certain value . For instance, if I set the reference value to 0, it would show Jun 20.

When I've looked at other answers - [like this one](https://superuser.com/questions/940648/excel-check-if-column-a-has-a-specific-value-if-so-display-another-cell-withi) - they rely on `VLOOKUP` but I suspect I need some `IF` statements. I'm sorry if there is already a relevant answer: I'm afraid I don't even know the terminology I need to search for !

Thanks all  !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the XLOOKUP function. While it doesn't let you specify a boolean criteria like "less than zero", there are other methods to get what you want.

For example, the following satisfies the criteria in your example:

```
=XLOOKUP(-0.001, B8:H8, B6:H6, "Never", -1,  1 )
            (i)   (ii)  (iii)   (iv)    (v) (vi)
```

Where:

(i) is the Lookup_value. This won't take a boolean like "<0", so instead you will choose an exact number at which to partition your data. Choose a number that is *small enough*. in this case, since the data consists of all whole numbers then anything *between* 0 and -1 will give you the desired result. I chose -0.001 since it is less than one cent.

Alternatively, if you set the lookup_value to exactly 0 it will tell you when you are ≤ 0 instead of just <0, which is probably what you want anyway.

(ii) is the search row, the values you are testing (row 8)

(iii) is the result row with the dates in them (row 6)

(iv) is the message you want to set if it doesn't find anything. "Never" makes sense here.

(v) Match_mode of -1 specifies that we want an *exact match, or the next lower value* and

(vi) Search_mode of 1 specifies that we want to *search forwards through the row*.

Note that you'll need to format cell B3 as the same date format as row 6 to have it display the date properly.

The advantage of this method is flexibility: your data doesn't have to be reshaped, reorganised or sorted in any particular way. As long as they are the same length, the values and dates can be anywhere you want, and you can play with search order and near match directions to get different results.

Answer (score 0):

If there are mutiple asserts is smaller than or equal to 0, which one do you want to quary the date?

Please check whether the formula is helpful, `=INDEX(B6:H6,0,MATCH(TRUE,B8:H8<=0,))`

[image]

Comment: Ah thank-you ! I don't have the reputatation to upvote this but this does work  !